# Xamarin.Forms: Web API Access To Mobile

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

Good Day Everyone. I am creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application.

In my solution, I have created a Xamarin Portable project and a WebForms project that will handle my Web Services and Database.
I've configured my **applicationhost.config** in the root folder of my VS2015 and set the binding to this :

```
     <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50857:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50857:192.168.1.11" />
     </bindings>
```

By doing that, I was able to access my WEB API even by changing the URL from **localhost** to **192.168.1.11** which is my IP ADDRESS.

[image]

I also tried to access it using **my phone's INTERNET BROWSER** by using my  **http://192.168.1.11:50857/api/Customer/** (laptop and mobile connected to the same network) and have a success in doing so.

But the real problem is, the **LIST of CLIENTS** from my WebForms project are **not being displayed** to my Xamarin Portable project.

My Mobile Application should access my WebForms project by getting its **WEB API** and use it in my RestClient WebServiceUrl.

What do you think is the reason behind this?

Here's my code for the WebForms project which handles the getting of data from my DB :

***WebFormsDemo project***

CustomerController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebFormsDemo;
using WebFormsDemo.ViewModel;

namespace WebFormsDemo.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        private EBMSEntities db = new EBMSEntities();

        // GET: api/Customer
        public IQueryable<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomerViewModels()

        {
            var displaycustomerInfo = from cust in db.CUSTOMERs
                                      select new CustomerViewModel
                                      {
                                          Id = cust.CUSTOMER_ID,
                                          CUSTOMER_CODE = cust.CUSTOMER_CODE,
                                          CUSTOMER_NAME = cust.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                                          CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NUMBER = cust.CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NUMBER,
                                          CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = cust.CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                                          CUSTOMER_CONTACT = cust.CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS + "," + " " + cust.CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NUMBER
                                      };




            return displaycustomerInfo;
        }

    }
}
```

CustomerViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebFormsDemo.ViewModel
{
    public class CustomerViewModel
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_CODE { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NUMBER { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_CONTACT { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_LANDLINE { get; set; }
        public string CUSTOMER_FAX_NUMBER { get; set; }
        public string ADDRESS { get; set; }
        public int LOCATION_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
        public int INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
        public int CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
        public int IS_DELETED { get; set; }
        public DateTime DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.

***XamarinForms Portable***

Here's my code for getting the WEB API of WebForms project:

RestClient.cs

```
public class RestClient_Customer<T>
{


    private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:50857/api/Customer/";

    public async Task<List<T>> GetCustomerAsync()
    {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
       httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

        var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

        return taskModels;
        }
 }
```

CustomerServices.cs

```
using Plugin.RestClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Services
{
    public class CustomerServices
    {


        public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomerAsync()
        {
            RestClient_Customer<Customer> restClient = new RestClient_Customer<Customer>();

            var customerList = await restClient.GetCustomerAsync(); //yung getasync ay pantawag as restclient

            return customerList;
        }


    }
}
```

CustomerVM.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Views;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class CustomerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private List<Customer> _customerList; // keep all customers
        private List<Customer> _searchedCustomerList; // keep a copy for searching
        private Customer _selectedCustomer = new Customer();

        private string _keyword = "";
        public string Keyword
        {
            get
            {
                return _keyword;
            }
            set
            {
                this._keyword = value;

                // while keyword changed we filter Employees
                //Filter();
            }
        }



        private void Filter()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_keyword))
            {
                CustomerList = _searchedCustomerList;

            }
            else
            {
                // var lowerKeyword = _keyword.ToLower();
                CustomerList = _searchedCustomerList.Where(r => r.CUSTOMER_NAME.ToLower().Contains(_keyword.ToLower())).ToList();
                //  EmployeesList = _searchedEmployeesList.Where(r => r.EMPLOYEE_NAME.Contains(_keyword)).ToList();


            }
        }




        public List<Customer> CustomerList
        {
            get
            {
                return _customerList;
            }
            set
            {
                _customerList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        public CustomerVM()
        {
            InitializeDataAsync();

        }

        private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
        {
            var customerServices = new CustomerServices();
            _searchedCustomerList = await customerServices.GetCustomerAsync();
            CustomerList = await customerServices.GetCustomerAsync();

        }




        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

ClientListPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.ClientListPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
             BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
             Title="Client List">


  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:CustomerVM/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" Text="{Binding Keyword}" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" x:Name="txtSearch" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList, Mode=TwoWay}"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              x:Name="listView">


      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <controls:CircleImage Source="icon.png"
                     HeightRequest="66"
                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     Aspect="AspectFill"
                     WidthRequest="66"
                     Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   />


              <Label Grid.Column="1"
                     Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_NAME}"
                     TextColor="#24e97d"
                     FontSize="24"/>



              <Label Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                       Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CODE}"
                       TextColor="White"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Opacity="0.6"/>


              <Label Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CONTACT}"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="18"
                   Opacity="0.6"/>



            </Grid>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>


    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             Padding="30,10,30,10"
             HeightRequest="20"
             BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             Opacity="0.5">
      <Label Text="© Copyright 2016   SMESOFT.COM.PH   All Rights Reserved "
             HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

ClientListPage.xaml.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
{
    public partial class ClientListPage : ContentPage
    {
        //CustomerListView listcustomer;
        //SearchBar searchbarcustomer;

        public ClientListPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
            InitializeComponent();

        }


    }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

This is my Current code for the XamarinForms project:

ClientListPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.ClientListPage"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
             BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
             Title="Client List">


  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:CustomerVM/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" Text="{Binding Keyword}" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" x:Name="txtSearch" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList, Mode=TwoWay}"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              x:Name="listView">


      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <controls:CircleImage Source="icon.png"
                     HeightRequest="66"
                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     Aspect="AspectFill"
                     WidthRequest="66"
                     Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   />


              <Label Grid.Column="1"
                     Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_NAME}"
                     TextColor="#24e97d"
                     FontSize="24"/>



              <Label Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                       Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CODE}"
                       TextColor="White"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Opacity="0.6"/>


              <Label Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Text="{Binding CUSTOMER_CONTACT}"
                   TextColor="White"
                   FontSize="18"
                   Opacity="0.6"/>



            </Grid>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>


    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             Padding="30,10,30,10"
             HeightRequest="20"
             BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             Opacity="0.5">
      <Label Text="© Copyright 2016   SMESOFT.COM.PH   All Rights Reserved "
             HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>




</ContentPage>
```

ClientListPage.xaml.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;



namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
{
    public partial class ClientListPage : ContentPage
    {

        CustomerVM viewModel;
        public ClientListPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);


            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new CustomerVM();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }

        async override protected void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            var json = await GetCustomerAsync();

            var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer[]>(json);

            foreach (Customer c in customers)
                viewModel.CustomerList.Add(c);
        }

        async Task<string> GetCustomerAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.11:50857/");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Customer");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else return response.ReasonPhrase;
        }


    }
}
```

CustomerVM.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Views;


namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class CustomerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customerList; // keep all customers
        private ObservableCollection<Customer> _searchedCustomerList; // keep a copy for searching
        private Customer _selectedCustomer = new Customer();

        private string _keyword = "";
        public string Keyword
        {
            get
            {
                return _keyword;
            }
            set
            {
                this._keyword = value;

                // while keyword changed we filter Employees
                //Filter();
            }
        }





        public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList
        {
            get
            {
                return _customerList;
            }
            set
            {
                _customerList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        public CustomerVM()
        {
         //   InitializeDataAsync();
            CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

Customer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Models
{
    public class Customer
    { 

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_CODE { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_CONTACT { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_LANDLINE { get; set; }
    public string CUSTOMER_FAX_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public int LOCATION_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
    public int INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
    public int CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID { get; set; }
    public int IS_DELETED { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to use the IP or FQDN of the machine hosting the service, not "localhost".

Comment: You are also using JSON deserialization when your service appears to be returning XML.

Comment: @Jason Sir I've tried changing the 'localhost' with my IP address but it does not work.

Comment: Inside your `CustomerVM` constructor, call `InitializeDataAsync` like this: `InitializeDataAsync().Wait()`.

Comment: @jstreet I've used the InitializeDataAsync().Wait() but the screen just seems to hang.

Comment: Suggestions: 1) move the creation of `CustomerVM` from your XAML to code-behind (like in my code sample). 2) move the population of `CustomerVM` (InitializeDataAsync) away from the constructor (like in my code sample). Use `OnAppearing` method, for instance (like in my code sample).

Comment: @jstreet alright Sir I'll try it right away.

Comment: @jstreet Sir should I move all the codes of my CustomerVM to my code behind?

Comment: `CustomerVM` is a regular class... it doesn't make sense to talk about code-behind here... what do you mean?

Comment: The creation of `CustomerVM` should be done inside `ClientListPage` code-behind, instead of `ClientListPage` XAML.

Comment: @jstreet Currently, I have codes for CustomerVM.cs right? Am I just gonna transfer it to my ClientListPage code-behind and delete the CustomerVM?

Comment: No, please don't do that.... let me update my code sample so our names match 1-to-1 and perhaps it is easier for you to follow.

Comment: @jstreet Okay Sir sorry for that.

Comment: I changed the naming in my code to match the naming in your code. Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of a **[MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)** conceptual mix up in your code, just because your Web API returns a collection of `CustomerViewModel`. I'd much rather have the API to return a collection of `Customer` and have it stored in my `CustomerViewModel`. But perhaps you're just giving bad names to things... impossible to say because you did not post a **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. So, I'll post a working one for you and perhaps it will help you sort things out:

**ClientListPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.ClientListPage">

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="{Binding ID}" FontSize="36"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="36"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

**ClientListPage.cs:**

```
public partial class ClientListPage : ContentPage
{
    CustomerVM viewModel;

    public ClientListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new CustomerVM();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    async override protected void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var json = await GetCustomersAsync();

        var customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerViewModel[]>(json);

        foreach (CustomerViewModel c in customers)
            viewModel.CustomerList.Add(c);
    }

    async Task<string> GetCustomersAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.0.0.17:55365/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Customers");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else return response.ReasonPhrase;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class CustomerVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> CustomerList { get; set; }

    public CustomerVM()
    {
        CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>();
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** In case that doesn't help, i suggest you to test your Web API using a `Console` client as below, and verify you get a valid JSON string (or error code, or exception):

> [{"ID":1,"Name":"Customer 1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Customer 2"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Customer 3"}]

```
class Program
{
    static string customers = "No customers";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            GetCustomersAsync().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine(customers);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task GetCustomersAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.0.0.17:55365/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Customers");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            customers = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else customers = response.ReasonPhrase;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir thanks for the answer. However, like what I've mention above,  the WebForms project is the one that handles the getting of data from my database, by using LINQ expression inside an API Controller named CustomerController, and the collection of it's Customer is stored on my CustomerViewModel. 

And my ClientListPage.xaml (MainPage in your example) is in my XamarinForms project. I don't know how am I going to access the CustomerViewModel on the WebForms project so I just tried to access the API of the CustomerController which is in my case is "http://localhost:50857/api/Customer/"

Comment: Sorry if I confused you Sir. I will just update my question and add the codes of my WebForms project here. Hope you can still help me please.

Comment: Please post full XAML and code-behind for your `ClientListPage`.

Comment: Sir I've added it now.

Comment: Sir just a question. How can I access the CustomerViewModel.cs to my ClientListPage.xaml.cs? Because my CustomerViewModel is in my WebFormsDemo project and the ClientListPage.xaml.cs is in my XamarinForms portable project?

Comment: Create a `CustomerViewModel` class in your Xamarin Portable project that is just the same as the one in the other project.

Comment: I've created one Sir and I name it 'Customer' but it gives me an error stating 'System.Net.WebException:Error: ConnectFailure(Network is Unreachable)'... What I did is I do not use anymore my RestClient because I already use your code :  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.0.0.17:55365/"); and replace it with my IP and Port.

Comment: Are you using the emulator or a real android device?

Comment: I'm using a real android device Sir connected via USB cable. Whenever I use my phone's internet browser to access http://192.168.1.11:50857/api/Customer/ I was able to see all the records. But in the actual mobile application, it does not appear.

Comment: Yes, the browser and your application are completely different applications, with different access rights, etc.... Note that **Network is unreachable** is as severe as it gets and has nothing to do with your Xamarin app or your web Api.... This is a matter of setting up your dev environment correctly at this point. Any reason why you can't use the emulator?

Comment: Sir I was able to fixed the error. However the list is still not displaying. Please check my current code.

Comment: Did you update your post with the new code? It still looks the same to me.

Comment: In your `ClientListPage.xaml` remove the block corresponding to the tag `<ContentPage.BindingContext>`.

Comment: Are you referring to this?   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:CustomerVM/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext> Am I gonna remove this all?

Comment: Yes, the whole thing.

Comment: Can you make anything appear in your screen? For instance: add `<Label Text="TESTING TESTING"/>` to your XAML.

Comment: Sir when I put a label inside the ListView.ItemTemplate, it was not being displayed.

Comment: Add a `<StackLayout>` and then inside it put the test label first plus your current `ListView` with everything it has inside.

Comment: It should look like this: <StackLayout><Label Text="TESTING"/><ListView>everything else you currently have inside here</ListView></StackLayout>.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't seem to display anything Sir. I've followed your instruction but it doesn't change anything. I've also noticed that even my searchbar doesnt seem to appear :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120497/discussion-between-jstreet-and-jaycee-evangelista).

Comment: Please go to the chat, we're not supposed to have long conversations here.